# Django request.user is not being passed into View Class get_context_data

Tags: django

I am currently working on getting the postman app integrated into my own website. When you want to access the inbox for postman, you need to be logged in. The code in the urls.py is

```
url(r'^inbox/(?:(?P<option>'+OPTIONS+')/)?$', InboxView.as_view(), name='inbox')
```

And the snippet of code that checks whether you are logged in is here:

```
class FolderMixin(NamespaceMixin, object):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    @login_required_m
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FolderMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...

class InboxView(FolderMixin, TemplateView):
    folder_name = 'inbox'
    view_name = 'inbox'   
    template_name = 'postman/inbox.html'`
```

Now my problem is in that the `request.user.is_authenticated` is not passed into the the `get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` above. So for example, in my base.html template, the below will show hihihihi:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
hihihihi
{% endif %}
```

meaning that the user is in fact authenticated. However when I test that out in the `get_context_data` function in `class FolderMixin` like the following:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        print("user is authenticated")
    print(self.request.user)
```

"user is authenticated" does not print and `self.request.user` returns `AnonymousUser`. So my question is why is request.user not passed into self.request.user and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the order of the extended classes, try this:

```
class InboxView(TemplateView, FolderMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: Dude, that is awesome! It's weird that postman has it the other way around. Is there a reason that the order matter? I am pretty new to python.

Comment: Sure there's: [here you have documentation for Python Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). When you use the method  `get_context_data` in `InboxView` you are using the method declared in `FolderMixin` in it fails because there's not a request there (yet) because `TemplateView` attributes come later, You should use your own mixins after Django's classes.